# How can I have two headers columns for the same column in a material UI table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple Material UI table, that will have what looks like a header cell in it's last column. However, I would like that this last header share the column with the header right before it.

Think of it like this: it will be 4 headers on the top, but only 3 columns, and the last two headers share the same column.

Not sure if I am making sense, so here is a [sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fast-qll47?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: You should use the attribute `colspan="2"` for the cell to expand for two columns. However, you need to bring `{v}` from `<TableCell>{v}</TableCell>` with that modification where you're getting `{v}` from. I tried `<TableCell colspan="2">{v}</TableCell>` but it's applying for every cell in the row where I changed it. Maybe you need to think about the way you construct the table. `colspan` is a commonly used parameter in HTML thus I'm not sure if it would be fully responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can collapse the Data row like this

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>Data 1</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Data 2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell colSpan={2}>Data Two Columns</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```